# Query date range columns with list of date parameters

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have an Oracle 10g table containing 2 date columns, DATE_VALID_FROM from and DATE_VALID_TO.

MY_TABLE:

```
DATE_VALID_FROM |   DATE_VALID_TO   |   VALUE

15-FEB-13       |   17-FEB-13       |   1.833
14-FEB-13       |   14-FEB-13       |   1.836
13-FEB-13       |   13-FEB-13       |   1.824
12-FEB-13       |   12-FEB-13       |   1.82
11-FEB-13       |   11-FEB-13       |   1.822
08-FEB-13       |   10-FEB-13       |   1.826
07-FEB-13       |   07-FEB-13       |   1.814
06-FEB-13       |   06-FEB-13       |   1.806
05-FEB-13       |   05-FEB-13       |   1.804
04-FEB-13       |   04-FEB-13       |   1.796
01-FEB-13       |   03-FEB-13       |   1.801
```

The range on the date columns isn’t always one day (weekends).

I can retrieve the value for a single date like this,

```
select DATE_VALID_FROM, DATE_VALID_TO, VALUE 
from MY_TABLE
where DATE_VALID_FROM <= TO_DATE('16-FEB-13', 'dd-MON-yy')
and DATE_VALID_TO >= TO_DATE('16-FEB-13', 'dd-MON-yy')
```

**Is it possible to retrieve the values for multiple random dates in a single query?**

e.g. Values for the 1st, 5th, 6th, 11th and 16th Feb.

Producing this result set:

```
DATE_VALID_FROM |   DATE_VALID_TO   |   VALUE

15-FEB-13       |   17-FEB-13       |   1.833
11-FEB-13       |   11-FEB-13       |   1.822
06-FEB-13       |   06-FEB-13       |   1.806
05-FEB-13       |   05-FEB-13       |   1.804
01-FEB-13       |   03-FEB-13       |   1.801
```

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you are trying to do.  You are trying to select the value for which dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select DATE_VALID_FROM, DATE_VALID_TO, VALUE 
from MY_TABLE M
JOIN (SELECT TO_DATE('01-FEB-2013') DATE_PARAM FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT TO_DATE('05-FEB-2013') DATE_PARAM FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT TO_DATE('06-FEB-2013') DATE_PARAM FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT TO_DATE('11-FEB-2013') DATE_PARAM FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT TO_DATE('16-FEB-2013') DATE_PARAM FROM DUAL) D
  ON M.DATE_VALID_FROM <= D.DATE_PARAM and M.DATE_VALID_TO >= D.DATE_PARAM
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/073a7/2)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a collection for this:

```
SQL> create type mydatetab as table of date;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> with dates as (select /*+ cardinality(t, 5) */ t.column_value thedate
  2                   from table(mydatetab(TO_DATE('16-FEB-13', 'dd-mon-rr'),
  3                                        TO_DATE('13-FEB-13', 'dd-mon-rr'))) t)
  4  select DATE_VALID_FROM, DATE_VALID_TO, VALUE
  5  from MY_TABLE, dates
  6  where dates.thedate between DATE_VALID_FROM and DATE_VALID_TO;

DATE_VALI DATE_VALI      VALUE
--------- --------- ----------
13-FEB-13 13-FEB-13      1.824
15-FEB-13 17-FEB-13      1.833
```

if you don't have privs to create one (ie this is just an adhoc thing). there may be some public ones you can use. check `select * from all_coll_types where elem_type_name = 'DATE'` for these.

p.s. you should always specify the format when you use dates. i.e. dont do :

```
TO_DATE('16-FEB-13')
```

but rather:

```
TO_DATE('16-FEB-13', 'dd-MON-rr')
```